Dual Boot Windows 10/11 Bluetooth Pairing
TLDR: How can I change a bluetooth pairing key in Windows to be the same as the one in another Windows installation? I have tried to export the .reg from one OS and paste to the other, but no luck.
For work-related issues I have to use Windows 10 and 11. I have both OS set-up in Dual Boot and on seperate drives. The issue is whenever I switch OS I have to repair my bluetooth headphones. I have looked up this problem and it seems to stem from each OS assigning a different pairing key whilst sharing a MAC adress. As I've said, I have accessed the registry with PsExex64 and tried to simply export on one machine and import on the next, but it just doesn't work and I end up having to re-pair my headphones.
I hope someone can help me, this is quite annoying. Thanks you for any help you may be able to provide.
